# How work with conditionnal stdout/stdin

Tags: command-line, bash, services

Initially, I want to check if a service is running or not in a bash script automaticly.
Then I found a command I don't understand but which work well :

```
/usr/sbin/service mysql status || /usr/sbin/service mysql start
```

or

```
if /usr/sbin/service mysql status > /dev/null
then
        echo "mysql running"
else
        echo "mysl not running"
fi
```

From my current knowledge, the left side should return something like false or empty but these concept don't exist in linux.

I understand stdin stdout stderr but here :
When the service is active or not the result of `service` exit to stdout.
So how linux make the difference between service start or not start ?
It doesn't check the text, it should have some false or 0 somewhere ...

How find it ? Am I completely wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with stdin/stdout. `||` means `or`.

First the left command is executed. If the return code is >0 (if status is ok) right side does not need to be executed as `1 or anything` is 1. If status returns 0, then right side is executed.

Comment: How do I display this return code ?

Comment: execute the command and immediately after that run `echo $?`